# Function Not Working When Abstracted to Service Layer in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a filter function that takes in user filter selections and returns data accordingly. Right now I am using this same function in multiple components, so to keep this DRY, what I'd like to do is refactor into a service layer. However, for some reason I'm not getting the implementation right, because the data isn't filtered as expected after refactoring part of the function into a service layer.

First off, here is the current component function -- that is working as expected:

```
public onFilterReceived(value, type, page) {
    if (value && type === 'lan') {
        this.language = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'location') {
        this.location = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'zip') {
        this.zipcode = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'firstName') {
        this.firstName = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'lastName') {
        this.lastName = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'branch') {
        this.branch = value;
    }

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        let data = resRecordsData.data;
    };

     this.filtersService.getByFilters(
        page, this.pagesize, this.currentStage, this.language, this.location, this.zipcode, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.branch, fn);
}
```

So, with that working, I tried refactoring the first part of the function - which handles the conditional logic based on what filters have been chosen - into a service layer. So my service layer looked like this:

```
public processByTypes(value, type) {
    let language, location, zipcode, firstName, lastName, branch;

    if (value && type === 'lan') {
        console.log(value);
        language = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'location') {
        location = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'zip') {
        zipcode = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'firstName') {
        firstName = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'lastName') {
        lastName = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'branch') {
        branch = value;
    }
}
```

And then in the component I refactored like so:

```
public onFilterReceived(value, type, page) {

    this.filtersService.processByTypes(value, type);

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        let data = resRecordsData.data;
    };

     this.filtersService.getByFilters(
        page, this.pagesize, this.language, this.location, this.zipcode, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.branch, fn);
}
```

But this isn't working.

I know the filter selections are making it to the service layer, because the console.log I have for "languages" successfully prints the value of the user's filter selection to the console. However, that value is not passed back to the component layer to then be used to filter the data accordingly. What am I missing in this implementation? It may be something fairly obvious, and maybe I've stared at it too long, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: In your working implementation, you are assigning the values to the corresponding property of `this` object in the component. However, when you moved it to a service, the values being assigned are to the local variable whose scope are only visible to the public method `processByTypes` within your service. Basically you are not returning something from the service method to be processed within your component after calling it. Is this the best way to achieve it? I’m not sure but that is why it isn’t working for you.

Comment: So perhaps if I have a return on each block of the function in the service layer? Will try playing with this.

Comment: Yeah, just play with it. Once you know the cause, just try avoid making the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables declared in `filtersService.processByTypes` are local variables.
They have no meaning after the end of the function unless you return those values.

You can return the values from the function like this:

```
public processByTypes(value, type) {
    let language, location, zipcode, firstName, lastName, branch;

    if (value && type === 'lan') {
        console.log(value);
        language = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'location') {
        location = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'zip') {
        zipcode = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'firstName') {
        firstName = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'lastName') {
        lastName = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'branch') {
        branch = value;
    }
    return {language:language, location:location, zipcode:zipcode, firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName, branch:branch};
}
```

and use it in the component like this:

```
public onFilterReceived(value, type, page) {

    let selections = this.filtersService.processByTypes(value, type);

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        let data = resRecordsData.data;
    };

    this.filtersService.getByFilters(
        page, this.pagesize, selections.language, selections.location, selections.zipcode, selections.firstName, selections.lastName, selections.branch, fn);
}
```

Comment: This looks generally correct. I have to do some additional tweaking to pull in values, but I think a variant of this will work. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, with ES6, you should be able to just do "return {language, location, zipcode, etc...}